# react-router Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to use the react-router but when I write a simple route doesn't work and the console show Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined.

Otherwise when I use without the react-router that work well

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>Hello World</div>
        );
    }
});


React.render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
  </Router>
), document.body);
```

The error is from this line of the react library

```
function autoGenerateWrapperClass(type) {
  return ReactClass.createClass({
    tagName: type.toUpperCase(), //<----
    render: function() {
      return new ReactElement(
        type,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        this.props
      );
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the whole stack trace?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are using examples from 1.0 Beta docs, but you are likely running the latest stable version (0.13). The docs in master are from 1.0 Beta, that's the source of confusion.

Read the docs for the latest stable version: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/docs

Answer (score 1):

My guess is when React.render is execute, the Router is not there yet. try this

```
 var routes = (
  <Route handler={App}>
  </Route>
);

Router.run(routes,(Root) => {
  React.render(<Root/>, document.body);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still wrapping my head around react-router, but the first thing I'd check is the version you're using and the docs your referencing. I was able to get it working by doing the following...

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>Hello World</div>
        );
    }
});

var routes = (
    <Route handler={App}>
    </Route>
);

window.onload = function() {
    ReactRouter.run(routes, ReactRouter.HistoryLocation, function(Root, state) {
        React.render(
            <Root />,
            document.getElementById('main')
        )
    });
};
```

Basically what [PhInside](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3700148/phinside) said, but wrapped in window.onload

Comment: I had to modify this line;  <Route handler={App}> to add path="myurl". And it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `<Route>` instead of `<Router>` in `React.render()`.