# Using react-router with the client-side library - I get errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've loaded the client-side library as the author suggests. "If you just want to drop a `<script>` tag in your page and be done with it, you can use the UMD/global build hosted on cdnjs."

ReactRouter is loaded onto the window object.

To render a Router, Route or Link I will need the ReactClass. But there I am stumped. I am using pure JavaScript so I want to do something like:

```
var router = React.createElement(ReactRouter.Router, null);
React.render(router, document.getElementById('container'));
```

But I just get an error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
```

Does anyone have an example of getting react-router to work with the CDN hosted client side library?

I'm using:

`13.0` of React and the JSX inline transpiler and `13.3` of React-Router. (I have the same error whether I do it in JSX or pure JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved for me by following the example in the answer by dionmampo on this ticket: [react-router Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990726/react-router-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-touppercase-of-undefined?rq=1)

Note the essential change added in my comment to make it work.

This doesn't quite explain my issue but does provide a working example of using React Router with the client side include. It suggests but doesn't prove that the key issue is the loading one: you need to wait till the Window has loaded before trying to run the Router.

Note that the Router, Route and Link are available on window.ReactRouter in this case.